# Problems with input masks in PartialViews - Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm having trouble with input masks (bootstrap) on all screens. I found the following interesting: All my Views that are returned in the form of "PartialView", the input masks do not work. For tests, when I create a View and a controller that returns a View, everything works correctly. This clearly shows that the problem is caused by the PartialView return from my controller.

I have several CRUD Views that are opened in Modal form from my Index. They only work if the return is PartialView. But the incoming mascots do not work at all ... Does anyone know how to solve this?

```js
//My Controller
 [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Policy = "CanWriteCepData")]
        [Route("cep-gerenciamento/editar-cep/{id}")]
        public IActionResult Edit(string id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var cepViewModel = _cepAppService.GetByCepId(id);

            if (cepViewModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return PartialView(cepViewModel);
        }
```

```js
@using SistemaComercial.Domain.ValueObjects
@model SistemaComercial.Application.ViewModels.Cep.CepViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Editar CEP";
}

<div>
    <form asp-action="Edit">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="modal-shadow">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="false">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-center"> @ViewData["Title"] </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                <div id="validationSummary" class="text-center">
                    <vc:summary />
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CepId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="txtCep" asp-for="CepId" class="form-control" data-plugin="formatter" data-pattern="[[99999]]-[[999]]" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CepId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Endereco" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <input id="txtEndereco" asp-for="Endereco" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Endereco" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Complemento" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <input asp-for="Complemento" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Complemento" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <label asp-for="Bairro" class="col-md-1 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input asp-for="Bairro" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Bairro" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Cidade" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input id="txtDescricao" asp-for="Cidade" class="form-control text-uppercase" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="Cidade" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="UF" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-2">
                            <input asp-for="UF" class="form-control text-uppercase" maxlength="2" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="UF" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PadraoSistema" disabled />
                                <label asp-for="PadraoSistema"></label>
                            </div>
                            <span asp-validation-for="PadraoSistema" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button id="btnSalvar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon wb-check"></i> Salvar </button>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                            <span title="Fechar" class="icon wb-close"></span> Fechar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
   
}
```

```js
//Field of View Edit containing the input Mask of Zip Code
 <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="CepId" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <input id="txtCep" asp-for="CepId" class="form-control" data-plugin="formatter" data-pattern="[[99999]]-[[999]]" />
                            <span asp-validation-for="CepId" class="text-danger"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

```js
//My Index with Generic Modal

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Gerenciar CEPS";
}

<div class="panel animsition">
    <div class="page-header">
        <h1 class="page-title">@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li><a asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="active">cep-gerenciamento/listar-todos</li>
        </ol>
        <div class="page-header-actions">
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm"
                 role="group">
                <a id="btnNovo" asp-action="Create" data-modal="" class="btn btn-outline btn-default new" data-toggle="tooltip"
                   data-original-title="Cadastrar Novo" data-container="body">
                    <span title="Cadastrar Novo" class="icon wb-plus"></span> Cadastrar Novo
                </a>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Configurações" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-settings" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Exportar" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-upload" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Importar" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-download" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Imprimir" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-print" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip"
                        data-original-title="Pesquisa Avançada" data-container="body">
                    <i class="icon wb-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    <span class="hidden-xs">Pesquisa Avançada</span>
                </button>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page-content">

        <table id="dtPrincipal" class="table table-striped table-bordered center-header " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Cep</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                    <th>Complemento</th>
                    <th>Bairro</th>
                    <th>Cidade</th>
                    <th>UF</th>
                    <th>Ações</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade modal-primary" id="modalCep" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="width: 50%; height: 500px;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div id="contentModal"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
    <script src="~/js/cadastros/cep/cep.js"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify sections in a partial view, or more appropriately, a view used as a partial view. This is why it works when returned as a view, but doesn't when returned as a partial view; in the former, the script is added to the section, while in the latter it is not.

For things like this, you should add the script directly to your layout, or to every view that will utilize one of these partials. You should pretty much never add any sort of JavaScript in a partial view as that can lead to all sorts of issues, such as scripts being loaded multiple times, loaded before dependencies are available, etc.

Comment: Hello @Chris Pratt!! In my case, the PartialViews Edit and Create open in a generic modal located in my Index. I did not quite understand where I should change, but I commented on the section scripts block in my View Edit and left only the section scripts in my Index. Only the Modal "Edit" window does not open .... :(

Comment: That's a different issue. Ensure that you don't have any JS errors on the page (look in the developer console in your browser). If you don't have any errors, or can't figure out how to solve the errors, create a separate question for that.